# Manipulating BufferedReader before it is read by OpenCSV's CSVReaderBuilder results in CSVReaderBuilder = null

Tags: java, opencsv

I am reading a CSV file OpenCSV's CSVReaderBuilder which doesn't work as the CSV file for some weird reason I cannot change has some lines with a missing column.

So I thought it would be a good idea to manipulate the BufferedReader I use as input for the CSVReaderBuilder and add an extra column before it is read by CSVReaderBuilder but unfortunately the CSVReaderBuilder will always return null.

This code results in an `com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException` as the lines have different number of columns, but works with a proper CSV file:

```
        FileInputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, charSet);
            BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

            // use own CSVParser to set separator
            final CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                    .withSeparator(separator)
                    .build();

            // use own CSVReader make use of own CSVParser
            reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(buffReader)
                    .withCSVParser(parser)
                    .build();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I added the code to manipulate the BufferedReader to add an extra semicolon if the column count is 13 instead of 14, but this will result in `reader` being null.

```
        FileInputStream is;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, charSet);
            BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

            buffReader.lines().forEach(t -> {
                String a[] = t.split(";");
                int occurence = a.length;

                if(occurence == 13) {
                    t = t.concat(";");
                }
            });         

            // use own CSVParser to set separator
            final CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
                    .withSeparator(separator)
                    .build();

            // use own CSVReader make use of own CSVParser
            reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(buffReader)
                    .withCSVParser(parser)
                    .build();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I find `CSVReader.readNext()` doesn't complain with uneven number of columns

Comment: The problem is not the uneven number of columns, but the different count of columns. Some lines are lacking one column. I need 14 columns, but some lines only have 13.

Comment: "Uneven" == differing number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

First, by the time `buffReader` is used in `new CSVReaderBuilder(buffReader)`, it has already been fully consumed by `buffReader.lines().forEach`. A `BufferedReader` can only be read once, in general. A solution could ordinarily be to create a new `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` on the same file, except in this case, you'll run into the second problem.

The line `t = t.concat(";");` does not work the way you expect. All this does is reassign the local variable `t`, which isn't used again. It does not change the contents of the file or the contents of the reader.

How to fix this is less straightforward. As far as I know, this exception will only be thrown when binding the CSV data to a bean, and only if fields are marked as `required = true`. Given that the source data does not always contain data for the last field, it seems like it should not be marked as required.

If manipulating the source data really is your only option, I can think of a few possible approaches:

1. Write the modified data back to a temporary file and then read that file with the CSV parser.
2. If the CSV file is small enough to fit into memory, you could write the modified data to a [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html), and then construct a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) with the result, and parse that.
3. Do the file content rewriting and CSV parsing in separate threads, using [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) and [`PipedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) to connect them.
4. Write a custom implementation of [`FilterReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) that transforms the file contents as they are read (not the most straightforward to implement).

Details of implementing these approaches would too long and broad for this answer, so I would suggest creating follow up questions if needed.

There might be additional options specific to the OpenCSV library that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tim, for looking into my problem and your detailed answer! The weird thing with the exception is that although its name is `com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException` it is not about required fields but about the completeness of a line and if all header lines do have a value. I retested this several times before writing here.

I will have a look on your kind suggestions and test them!

Comment: After reading in all four ways of implementation I decided to implement my own FilterReader as it fit best my needs. I can now perfectly rebuild the whole input file on the go. This is just great! Thank you!